# Hadoop use folder structure as input

Tags: hadoop

I'm a beginner trying to use Hadoop and I guess although I understand the general map-reduce stuff I seem to miss something in the beginning.

Basically I'm trying to parse a website (local) using hadoop and have as result the link structure (so that later I can calculate some page rank).

Thus the input is a folder structure (with subfolder and files) and the output should be, for now, each file with a list of files that link to it.

What InputFormat should I use? The FileInputFormat doesn't seem to work (I get an exception upon encountering a folder - saying it is a directory). Actually is there such an InputFormat that allows for inputing such folder structures?

If not... should I somehow preprocess the input data? Meaning should I take out every HTML file into a single directory and look from it there?
Or, is there a way to write such an InputFormat that does what I need?

Answer (score 2):

> Actually is there such an InputFormat that allows for inputing such folder structures?

All the FileInputFormats take a Path as an input, which can be a directory or file.

> The FileInputFormat doesn't seem to work (I get an exception upon encountering a folder - saying it is a directory).

The [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-1501) has been fixed in some of the releases (0.21, 0.22, 0.23 and trunk). o.a.h.mapred.FileInputFormat should have the addInputPathRecursively method implemented. Also, noticed that it's not implemented in the new API (o.a.h.mapreduce.FileInputFormat). Here is the [code](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileInputFormat.java) for o.a.h.mapred.FileInputFormat class from trunk.

BTW, what release are you using?

> Basically I'm trying to parse a website (local) using hadoop and have as result the link structure (so that later I can calculate some page rank).

Because of the media attention/hype Hadoop is being used for every thing. Hadoop as-is works well for some types of problems. Consider using Apache [Hama](http://incubator.apache.org/hama/) and [Giraph](http://incubator.apache.org/giraph/) for graph processing. Note that both are in incubator and documentation is also sparse.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm using version 1 of Hadoop. I'll give the new FileInputFormat a try to see how it works.

Comment: Version 1.0.x is re-branding of 0.20.* code base and doesn't have the required API. Go with 0.22 release, since 0.23 has got a lot of architectural changes and is a lot different from 1.0.x.